# How to get an object of session in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have java class in JSF which act as a Scheduler and it runs every five seconds  in background to perform some updates  in DB.

since it is not declared as a bean in faces config or via annotation, i am not able to get session using

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

Class scheduler{
    public void Scheduler(){
        HttpSession session = getSession();  // throughing null pointer    Exception.
    }
}


private HttpSession getSession()
{
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

    return session; 
}
```

How can I get an object of session in this Scenario ?

Comment: Hi Balu, above link does not address my problem because in order to get session Object  first you must have FacesContext's object in hand. I have read your article  on creating FacesContext object inside doFilter() method, but again  for that you must have objects of request and response.  but in my class i dont have any thing at all.

Comment: Hi Balu, could you please add a  code snippet w.r.t my code above to get an object of session via facesContext. Also,  Work work = (Work) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("work");   i didn't get one thing that where  "work"  has been set ?

Comment: Hi Balu, still i am getting null pointer Exception, could you please modify above code  to make it work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90210/discussion-between-lokendra-lovely-and-balusc).

Comment: hi Balu, my scheduler is an independent file. As soon my application starts , it starts processing records.
i guess your answer is applicable when my scheduler is a part of backing bean.